# Select rows that meet ALL of a dynamic set of ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

I have a table that I want to be able to query to get rows that are in a defined sets of value.  I can create new table structures if required as this is temporary data used for a leaderboard of sorts.

The Token Sets can be created by grouping many tokens together.  What I want to do it find all the Addresses that have ALL tokens in a defined set.

Not sure if I need to re model the data, or if I'm just missing a simple query setup.

So in the data below I would want to return Address 1234 based on TokenSet "SetA".

**Token Address**

| TokenID | Address |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1234 |
| BB | 1234 |
| CC | 1234 |
| DD | 1234 |
| AA | 4321 |
| CC | 4321 |

**Token Sets**

| TokenID | Set |
| --- | --- |
| AA | SetA |
| BB | SetA |
| CC | SetA |

Comment: provide your desired result

Comment: Does it matter if they have *other* tokens also? Say there was also `EE, 1234`

Comment: Token Address table gets populated each hour via a script.  Token Sets can be created at any time and are based by selecting TokenIDs and creating a Set.

I want to be able to run a query to get a List of Addresses that have TokenSets

So in this case Address "1234" have a TokenSet "SetA"

Comment: So what result do you want if there are `TokenAddress` rows which are *not* part of `SetA` do we just ignore those and ensure that all `SetA` rows *are* present? Or do you want to have an exact match for the whole set of rows

Comment: Your answer below seems to be working for me, but I need to add more data to make 100% sure but just having the concept helps a ton to work off.  I'm basically trying to look at what TokenSets an Address has and then also what Addresses a TokenSet has.  I have been able to to take what you provided to get a working version for both of my cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is classic [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).** There are quite a number of different solutions.

If you want to do this across multiple sets at the same time, one way is to use a window function

```sql
SELECT
  ts.[Set],
  ta.Address
FROM TokenAddress ta
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      Total = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ts.[Set])
    FROM TokenSet ts
) ts ON ta.TokenID = ts.TokenID
GROUP BY
  ts.[Set], ta.Address
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(ts.Total);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e416/5)

Comment: At first test this seems to be working as expected, thanks also for the link to do more research into the RD

Answer (score 2):

If sets and addresses contains non-repeated tokenIDs, you can do:

```
select a.address
from token_sets s
join token_address a on a.tokenid = s.tokenid
where s.set = 'SetA'
group by a.address
having count(*) = (select count(*) from token_sets where set = 'SetA')
```

Comment: I get the following error:  Column 'token_sets.set'  is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.